# How do I add freeglut to a Visual Studio project?

Tags: c++, graphics, visual-studio, glut

I am working on making a game for Windows in c++. I have previously made games for Ubuntu using freeglut, and I found freeglut for windows, but when I added it to the `Configuration Properties\VC++ Directories\Library Directories` tab in visual studio, visual studio complains about 'undefined reference' whenever I use a freeglut method. Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 2):

When you right click on the project you have to also add the filename of the library under "Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies".

Just in case: You also have to tell Visual Studio where to find the header files in case you haven't yet. This can be done under "VC++ Directories->Include Directories"

Make sure you define the right libraries for Debug and Release builds. Most libraries have libraries/dlls with d added to the name that can be used for debugging. Switch the Configuration between Debug and Release in oder to set input files. Of course you can use the release libraries for Debug too.